# Web Container Thread reported as hung in WAS

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, websphere-8

I am frequently seeing the following exception in the SysOut logs. The exception stack trace indicates that the web container thread in waiting on a DB operation to complete. But, I don't have such long running DB queries in the applications. And most importantly I see this exception in my higher environments: UAT (Clustered) and unable to replicate in lower environments. DEV / SIT.

```
Exception stack trace:
00000086 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 1" (000000ae) has been active for 631219 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 2 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:132)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1112)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:714)
```

There is a firewall / router between the WAS and DB server in the higher environment. As this doesn't happen in lower environments, I am suspecting this is happening because of the way servers are setup in higher environment.

Could anyone point me out the different properties or setting I need to check in the higher environment? - WAS, OS, Router Configurations etc.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the solution given by IBM here(http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448485). This might be the issue with some specific Resultset get statements. Please check here(http://www.coderanch.com/t/512637/Websphere/application-hangs-closing-database-connection).

Comment: Do you have messages that thread has been finished or they hang forever? When you will see that message, check using Oracle tools if there are any running statements on the database side.